# IntegrityError error when testing a Django application using Selenium

Tags: python, django, selenium, django-testing, django-tests

I am testing a django application using selenium, and my code looks something like this:

```
class MyLiveServerTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        super(MyLiveServerTestCase, self).setUp()
        self.client = Client()
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.browser.stop = lambda x: WebDriverWait(self.browser, x).until(lambda x: False)
        self.browser.get_body = lambda: self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')

    def tearDown(self):
        super(MyLiveServerTestCase, self).tearDown()
        self.browser.quit()

    def login_staff(self):
        User.objects.create_superuser('abc', 'abc@gmail.com', '1234')
        # User opens his web browser, and goes to the website
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
        # User types in his username and passwords and hits return
        username_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('username')
        username_field.send_keys('abc')
        password_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('password')
        password_field.send_keys('1234')
        # User submits the form
        password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        body = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
        self.assertIn('abc', body.text)
```

When I run this test case for `login_staff`, I am getting an error

> IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

Since on the start my every test case, I am creating a new database and User instance, then why this integrity error? Is there a way to flush previous database here? Any idea why this error keep on coming even though a new database is created while running this test?

Comment: Seems weird - Live server test case should be creating a new DB for each test. Try seeing what users are already in the database prior to this line:
User.objects.create_superuser('abc', 'abc@gmail.com', '1234')
using print or pdb: `print [user.username for user in User.objects.all()]'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it the error is weird.

Comment: Did you have any existing users?

Comment: Yes, it is showing me one existing user? Any idea how to flush this user ?

Comment: When I run it without using the `User.objects.create_superuser('abc', 'abc@gmail.com', '1234')`, it showing me broken pipe :/

Comment: Hey I noticed that my function `login_staff` is executing two times not sure why. First they it prints out `User.objects.all() - []` and then `User.objects.all() - <User: abc>`. Finally the program goes into `error`

Comment: Okay I have resolved it, I was calling two times the same `login_staff` function :(